# Use Apache SSL client certificate to identify a client to a server while restricting the client from copying SSL certificate

Tags: apache-http-server, ssl, ssl-certificate

I want to use SSL certificates to identify a client to an Apache server. The client runs Firefox on CentOS 7 on a laptop that I loan out. The client network connection uses NAT so multiple clients will appear to the web server as having the same IP. Only the laptop that I loan out should be able to access the server.  I've read the documentation on SSL client certificates and that seems easy enough to setup. However,  I don't want the user to be able to copy the certificate from the Firefox install to their own laptop. 
It seems to me that if Firefox can read the certificate then the user can copy it as well.  The user also has shell access on the laptop because they are using the laptop to write a test.

Answer (score 0):

What you say is true, if a client can read a file, he can also copy it. You could make it more difficult, but they are usually only stop-gap measures.

If you want to make it really secure, you could issue the client with a smartcard. The smartcard is designed to hold a private key and to never let that private key leave the smartcard (or be copied). You could also store a private key in the TPM chip that might be in the laptop (TPM is like a smartcard, but built-in to the computer). This will make it nearly impossible to copy.

Comment: This sounds very interesting. The laptops are Lenovo T540, T550, and T560 and I think they do support TPM.  I will have to see if there is CentOS 7 support for TPM. However, it's not clear how one might use it with Apache authentication. Have you done that?

Comment: The Apache configuration you can get straight of the internet (search for "mutual authentication SSL"). The interesting part is getting the TPM chip to communicate with Firefox. I tried it a few years ago, but after 2 days of messing around, gave up and used a USB smartcard reader with a smartcard :) Support might be better now.